# Python - Function is invoked twice

Tags: python-3.x

I created a function in python which I invoke from another file. However, it is getting invoked twice.

The following function is in **test.py** -

```
def test_fun():
    print("test fun invoked")
```

I am invoking that function from **__init__.py** file as follows

```
from sample.test import test_fun

test_fun()
```

But `test_fun` is getting executed twice.

I am getting the output as-

```
test fun invoked

test fun invoked
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: first thing you do wrong is you did not provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as the question is stated now we cant answer what went wrong, maybe try to remove the function call and if the function is still called it is because of the import ... any answer would be a guess

Comment: Thanks, @DerteTrdelnik, But I have already check that if I remove the function call than the function don't execute. I also tried to change the import as I import only the file not, a particular function, but it's also not worked for me.

Comment: @Arun Please look at the post that Derte linked you too. Without providing that information as an [edit] to your question - there's nothing anyone can help you with.

Comment: @DerteTrdelnik, Please review the edited question, Not sure but I think it is happening because I am invoking the function from the __init__ file. Am I right?

Comment: Can you tell which file you are executing? Are you directly running the `init` file or are you executing a different file?

Comment: @HaranRajkumar yes I am executing __init__ file directly.

Comment: @ArunKumar I have tried to replicate your output. I have the same two files. `__init__.py` is in the root folder. `test.py` is in a folder `sample` in the root. I ran the `__init__.py` file and the function is getting invoked only once. Can you provide your file structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__init__.py` gets executed whenever you load a package since there is a function call in it it will get executed even if you import something from the package
see [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

you should wrap executions meant for when the module itself is executed in a check whether it is actually called as a main otherwise the modules are not safe to be imported...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_fun()
```